# Rally 2.1 SDK Filter Story on Feature

Tags: sdk, rally

I am trying to filter user stories for a given Feature ID as in code below but I get no results.
I have tried Feature.FormattdID and Feature.ObjectID both but it's not fetching all stories under the feature.
What should be correct way of filtering with feature ID?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Custom Store Grid Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.1/sdk.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        Rally.onReady(function() {
          Ext.define('CustomApp', {
              extend: 'Rally.app.App',
              componentCls: 'app',

              launch: function() {
                var filters = [
             {property:'Feature.FormattedID',operator:'=',value: 'F1234'},
                          ];
                          Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore',{
                              autoLoad: true,
                              model:'UserStory',
                              filters:filters,
                              listeners: {
                                  load: function(store,records,operation) {
                                      console.log('load store', store, records, operation);
                                  }
                              }
                          });
              },


              });
                Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
                  name: 'Custom Store Grid Example'
                });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">

        </style>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That all looks right to me.  My guess is that your implicit project scoping is causing your app to only load the feature children that are in your current project scope.  If you add a context config to your store to scope to the entire workspace I bet it'll work:

```
context: {
    workspace: this.getContext().getWorkspaceRef(),
    project: null
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now to think of it, this was so logical :-)